# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm getting a `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null` error and I can't find why.

Here is the stack trace :

```java
at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions(UTF_8.java:77)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.access$200(UTF_8.java:57)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.overflow(UTF_8.java:572)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:602)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:691)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:230)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:603)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
    // Some more of     at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:112)
    // at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128)
```

I've got a method `deletePreviousJobs` as below :

```java
public void deletePreviousJobs() {
    List<DataJob> previousJobs = jobRepository.findAllByStatus(JobStatus.OLD.getCode());
    for (DataJob jobToDelete : oldJobs) {
        deleteJob(jobToDelete.getId());
    }
}
```

And the `deleteJob`:

```java
public void deleteJob(Long jobId) {
    clearProductsForJobId(jobId);
    clearPaymentsForJobId(jobId);
    // other methods
}
```

And the `clearProductsForJobId`:

```java
  public void clearProductsForJobId(Long jobId){

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    // Here, page Size is set to 4000
    Page<Product> productResults = productRepository.findAllByJobId(jobId, PageRequest.of(0, pageSize));
    int currentPage = 1;
    int totalPageCount = productResults .getTotalPages();

    LOGGER.info("CLEARING PRODUCTS FROM TABLE - Total number of rows to delete : {} ", productResults .getTotalElements());

    while(productResults .hasNext()){

      LOGGER.info("Start DELETING page {} / {} ", currentPage, numberOfPages);
      productRepository.deleteInBatch(productResults.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
      productResults = productRepository.findAllByJobId(jobId, productResults.nextPageable());
      currentPage++;

    }

    long durationTimeInSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((System.nanoTime() - startTime), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    LOGGER.info("PRODUCTS CLEARED in {}s",  durationTimeInSeconds);
  }
```

I know that `StackOverFlowError` occurs when the amount of call stack memory allocated by JVM is exceeded. However, I can't understand why it happens in my case ?

For a given `jobId`, I have around 800000 `Product.

1. What am I doing wrong ?
2. I tried to switch `pageSize` value from 4000 to 2500 => In that case, everything works fine.
   Does that mean I cannot have a `pageSize` value greater than 2500 ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: When I remove the `while` and just requests the first page, it also throws the same error.

So I tried to only fetch the first page without the `deleteInBatch` => everything works fine.
Then when I add de `deleteInBatch`, it throws the same error.
How is that possible ? Is there any limitations with `deleteInBatch`?

Comment: You need to look through the stack trace until you find where your code is being called or doing the calling. You didn't provide that part in your post. Somewhere, you're doing something (likely in a loop) that's allocating a lot of memory (ie, objects probably).

Comment: I've found that this is symptom is usually due to infinite recursion...which the bottom of that stack trace sure looks like!  The `ASTPrinter.showAst` method seems to be calling itself at line 128 of the `ASTPrinter` class's code.  I have no idea why it would do that.

Comment: @SnakeDoc : thanks for your answer. I didn't put the whole stacktrace because  I'm only getting a at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.ASTPrinter.showAst(ASTPrinter.java:128) until the end of the stack trace (this is why I've added the comment in the stacktrace). One thing I don't understand, why this does not happen when I change the pagesize from 4000 to 3000?

Comment: @sewey it will have your code somewhere in the stack trace. check again. your code is calling some method, which is setting off the chain reaction you're seeing in the rest of your stack trace. There's a line number somewhere, and that's where you should start troubleshooting this. Steve is right, there's a good possibility of unterminated recursion.